# Get list of all registered .net and .com domain names

Tags: list, search, dns, tld

I want to develop a site for instant domain availability search(.com and .net only). For that I need list of all the registered domain. I searched on google and came to know about **VegiSign's TLD Zone File Access Program**( http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/grow-your-domain-name-business/tld-zone-access/index.xhtml?loc=en_US).

But it requires me to fill some forms and the process will take upto 4-8 weeks.

Is there any other way I can get access of all registered domains(including commercial services).

Comment: The TLD zone file access program might not be good for an instant domain availibility search site because you can only pull the TLD zone file once per day. Any domains registered since you pulled the file would show up as available even though it is not.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/307553/632951

Comment: @MichaelKrebs That and also the fact that you can register a domain name without  it being published so it won't appear in the zonefile but yet can not be registered because it is already.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek When you say "without it being published," do you mean that you can register a domain name, and the TLD nameservers won't have any NS records in the TLD zone file for your domain name? I am not familiar with that option. It is my understanding that registering a domain name always adds NS records for that domain name to the TLD zone file, in which case it would always appear in VeriSign's TLD Zone File Access Program. How would one register a domain name without publishing it?

Comment: "do you mean that you can register a domain name, and the TLD nameservers won't have any NS records in the TLD zone file for your domain name?" Yes, you can register domain names without nameservers attached to it. "  It is my understanding that registering a domain name always adds NS" Not true. And even if it was you can change nameservers at any time, and hence remove them. Also domains can be on "clientHold" or "serverHold" and then will not be published. See https://icann.org/epp

Comment: "How would one register a domain name without publishing it? " Registering and publishing are two different things. A domain is published if it has nameservers and if it is not on clientHold or serverHold status. When you register a domain name (or later update it) you decide which nameservers to use, from zero to a certain number (depending on registrars and registries). See for example right now `beauty.discount`. It exists in whois so it is registered, but it is not published in registries authoritative nameserver because it has no nameservers.

Comment: And it is the same case in all TLDs (so nothing specific to Verisign or any other registry), except in VERY rare cases of registries requiring a domain to have at least 2 nameservers. Some ccTLDs do that. But it is really the exception, in almost all TLDs a domain can have 0 nameservers and hence not be published. It may be as much as a few percentage of all domain names registered (accounting for clientHold/serverHold also, first one can be used by registrars at expiration time, second one by registries during disputes)